# Multitouch issue: when pressing two buttons at the same time, it detects as if I touched only one with my fingers, why?

Tags: android, button, multi-touch

So I have two buttons and would like to press both at the same time. If I press the first it logs a "C" (as a piano note), the other logs a D.

So far:

```
@Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             switch (v.getId()) { 
                case R.id.cnotebutton: 
                    Log.i("C", "C1");
                    return true;
                case R.id.c2notebutton: 
                      Log.i("D", "D1");
                      return true;
                default:
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;  
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                switch (v.getId()) { 
                    case R.id.cnotebutton:
                        Log.i("C", "C2");
                        return true;
                    case R.id.c2notebutton: 
                          Log.i("D", "D2");
                          return true;
                    default:
                    }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;
            default:

        }
        return true;
    }
```

I Log C1 and C2 to distinguish the cases, but every time I press the buttons I get only C1,C2 or D1,D2 as if I touched the same buttons with both of my fingers. I should get C1,D2 or D1,C2 depending on which finger pointed first. Any suggestions? 
Anyway I havent found a piano sample project yet, but that would definetly help me, if this is not going to work or my approach is totally wrong. Is there any?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)`is what you are looking for. Take a look at [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)